# My DIV won't display inline with the previous DIV css

Tags: html

I have 2 divs in my site and I want these to be inline with each other in mobile view. But it seems that my 2 divs won't align with each other.

```
        <div class="select-form-1">
            <span>전체검색</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-search">
            <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="검색어를 입력하세요.">
        </div>
```

These are my 2 divs. The first one is a selection box and the other one is an input field.

```
.input-search {
    display: inline;
}
.select-form-1 {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

IN my media queries, it won't align with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `display: block;` property on your `.select-form-1` class with `display: inline;`:

```
.select-form-1 {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` in `select-form-1` is preventing it. If you want them to sit side by side, you can

- make them both `display: inline-block` (or `inline`), in which case you also have to make sure their combined widths aren't wider than the width of their container.
- make their parent container `display: flex`.